# How to get a specific component of an equation without hardcoding?

Tags: parametric-functions, list-manipulation

Say I define an equation `line[t_] = {t, 2t, 3t}`. What code will define `x[t] = t`, `y[t] = 2t`, and `z[t] = 3t`, but without hardcoding?

Comment: `Evaluate[Through[{x, y, z}[t_]]] = line[t]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but without hardcoding?

First of all, `line[t_] = {t, 2t, 3t}` is not an equation. Equation should have `==` in it. This is function definition. Second, better to use delayed `:=` instead of immediate `=` when making functions, unless there is a good reason to use immediate definition.

I do not know why you do not want to do normal explicit definitions for `x[t_]` and `y[t_]` and `[z_]` it would be more clear when looking at the code that way.

But this does what you want. I am sure there are other ways to do it.

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, t];
line[t_] := {t, 2 t, 3 t}
MapThread[(#1[t_] := #2) &, {{x, y, z}, line[t]}];
```

And now you have these functions defined.

[image: Mathematica graphics]